# Is there anyway to reverse engineer fields from existing schema using haskelldb or any other haskell library?

Tags: mysql, haskell, haskelldb

I'm looking to port some python scripts to haskell, the scripts use sqlalchemy(ORM) that lets you reverse engineer models from existing DB schema which is quite handy. I'm not sure if there's any library in haskell which lets you do the same thing. I think haskelldb has an ORM-like approach so I was wondering if it lets you do reverse engineering as well. I don't mind if it's a different library other than haskelldb, if I can reverse engineer then it will save a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [groundhog-inspector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/groundhog-inspector) package was just announced today on reddit [(link)](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2o9vmt/ann_groundhoginspector_a_tool_for_generating/)
 and may do what you want.